# Save lambda function to file without references to other variables / explicitly

Tags: python, lambda, static

I'm trying to save a lambda function explicitly in Python. With explicitly I mean without references to variables (or is this called static?).

Minimum working example:

```
from argparse import Namespace
from math import asin
import dill as pickle  # Use 'dill' because it can pickle lambda functions, which 'pickle' cannot.


def save_data_to_file(data_to_save, file_name):
    with open(file_name, 'wb') as data_to_save_file:
        pickle.dump(data_to_save, data_to_save_file)


def load_data_from_file(file_name):
    with open(file_name, 'rb') as data_to_save_file:
        data = pickle.load(data_to_save_file)
    return data


# Definition function.
constant = 1
my_function = lambda x: asin(x) + constant

# Save function.
data_to_save = {'my_function': my_function}
file_name = 'my_function.input'
save_data_to_file(data_to_save, file_name)

# Delete variables for the sake of testing correct loading of the function.
print(my_function(0.15))
del my_function
del constant

# Load function.
data_loaded_from_file = load_data_from_file(file_name)
dlff = Namespace(**data_loaded_from_file)
print(dlff.my_function(0.15))  # NameError: name 'constant' is not defined
```

I get the error `NameError: name 'constant' is not defined`. So what I want is to save `my_function` such that it uses `constant` once but does not need it anymore after it has been defined. In that way, I could load `my_function` without Python complaining about not knowing `constant`.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Unrelated but you shouldn't be using `lambda` to define named functions - that's what the `def` statement is for.

Comment: why cant you use a normal function instead, with default value of `constant`=0, `def func(x,constant=0):` `return asin(x) + constant`, pass it to the function if and when you want to add a constat

Answer (score 0):

If you want the constant to be part of the function, you have to make it part of the function:

```
my_function = lambda x, constant=1: asin(x) + constant
# or
my_function = lambda x: asin(x) + 1
# or
import functools
temp_func = lambda x, constant: asin(x) + constant
my_function = functools.partial(temp_func, constant=1)
```

Alternatively if you absolutely need the constant to not be a parameter but still dynamic you can achieve this with eval. I would highly advise against it though.

```
constant = 1
my_function = eval("lambda x: asin(x) " + str(constant))
```